# Why tensorflow.one_hot is not sparse?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, tensorflow2.0

Take the following example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
indices = [0, 1, 2]
depth = 3
tf.one_hot(indices, depth)
```

which outputs:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=9, shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

The one-hot tensor is dense. I wonder if this representation is efficient, particularly if one has many categories. So why is the `one_hot` output dense by default? Wouldn't a sparse representation be more memory cheap?

Comment: How could a sparse representation finally be used in matrix computation?

Comment: I'm confused, isn't the sparse representation what you just passed `tf.one_hot` (not exactly, but it isn't hard to get to sparse rep from that)? So if you want the sparse representation can't you just go with the input itself?

Comment: @Sraw there are sparse matrix libraries that make it quite efficient to do operations in sparse mode.

Comment: @user1269942 Well, anyway, as your answer says, you got my point.

Comment: @Sraw  Got it. I took your question literally(and isolated and atomically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite likely because if you think of the output of a typical neural net for classification, it is a dense vector of likelihoods. In order for the optimization algorithm to modify the weights of the neural net, the error vector must be calculated. The error(or really, the squared error) is the sum of the outputs - truth values(squared).  So to natively represent the one hot encoding in sparse format will only lead to *un-sparsifying* for the optimization/backprop operations.  This *un-sparsifying* would just be a waste that would be done every training iteration.

To address the extra space...true, it is a bit more space but the labels *usually* comprise a small fraction of modern training data with the actual input(image/audio/etc.) being much larger.

My thoughts follow the assumption that one-hot vectors are used for labels...that's where I use them most anyway.

For the sake of argument, if you were to have some custom layers and inputs that were compatible with sparse representations and *needed* to have a sparse label representation, then a one-time conversion to sparse wouldn't hurt your performance as it would be a one-time(or maybe a few times) cost using pretty fast libraries(scipy, for example).